# Crear una lista de números reales en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, numpy

Quiero crear una lista de números de 0 hasta rhom=0.2 con paso de drho=0.02, tengo mi código abajo, pero al momento de ejecutar me devuelve

```
[0.]
```

Mi código

```
import numpy as np 
a = -20;
b= 20;
T=4;
M=500;
rhom=0.2;
n=10;
drho=rhom/n;
rho=np.arange(0,drho,rhom)
print(rho)
```

Comment: Me parece que tienes invertidos unos parámetros, prueba: `rho=np.arange(0,rhom,drho)`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, una solución para lo que quieres sería algo así:

```
import numpy as np 
a = -20;
b= 20;
T=4;
M=500;
rhom=0.2;
n=10;
drho=rhom/n;
rho=np.linspace(0,drho,n)
print(rho)
```

Ensayala y si te sirve, califica la respuesta!.